# using Object prototype in Angular expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I use `Object.keys(obj).length` in an angular Expression?

For example, this does not work:

`{{Object.keys(obj).length}}`

even though

`{{obj}}` prints out a JSON object.

Comment: Pretty sure you got to use use a function - pass your obj to it

Comment: Yea, i figured i'd pass it into the `ng-init` and use it from there. just curious why `Object` is out of scope or something..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to add `Object.keys` function to the scope :

```
$scope.getKeys = Object.keys;
```

And then in the template :

```
{{getKeys(obj).length}}
```

Comment: Good workaround. Out of my way, Angular.

Answer (score 3):

> just curious why Object is out of scope or something

Because `Object` methods are not allowed in Angular expressions. Check [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/parse.js#L57) for parser if you want to see what else is disallowed.

```
// ...
} else if (// block Object so that we can't get hold of dangerous Object.* methods
    obj === Object) {
  throw $parseMinErr('isecobj',
      'Referencing Object in Angular expressions is disallowed! Expression: {0}',
      fullExpression);
}
```

What you can do instead is to expose necessary method or object to the scope explicitly using `$scope` object.